# IIS 10 StaticFile handler impeding PHP custom verb for default document

Tags: php, iis, default-document, handler-mappings, httpverbs

I'm trying to enable IIS 10 to allow custom verbs in PHP. I have PHP_via_FastCGI enabled to accept all verbs. This works correctly when I specify the full path, inclusive of index.php at the end.

The issue is when I don't specify index.php in the URL endpoint. It seems under that circumstance, the StaticFile handler takes over and I get the following error that references the StaticFile handler:

```
HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.
```

The StaticFile handler is also set to allow all verbs.

It's also worth noting that during my investigation I have removed all other handlers (aside from PHP_via_FastCGI and StaticFile) for the site for anything referencing a * path. WebDav is also not installed. My Web.config is essentially blank. I have full administrator access to the server.

Is there another way to configure the PHP_via_FastCGI handler to handle default documents, thereby removing the StaticFile handler? Or is there a configuration within StaticFile that I'm missing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I have circumvented the issue by disabling the StaticFile handler within Web.config and adding a URL rewrite rule. At first glance, this appears to be working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <handlers>
        <remove name="StaticFile"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
            <rules>
            <rule name="Lang-Redirect">
                    <match url="(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/index.php" />
            </rule>
            </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```